# SQLite performance choice on Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am developing an application on Android using SQLite. I am quite new to SQLite so I want to ask about a design choice.

If you want to pass an object (which represents a row in the DB) from one activity to another, which one of the below is faster and/or resource efficient?

- Serializing the object as JSON, sending with intent and deserializing on the other end
- Sending only record ID and pulling the record from the DB again in the other activity

Either case, what would be the performance difference between these two choices?

Comment: You could also maintain an object manager that manages a mapping of table indicies to objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really does depend on the size of your row. If it's relatively small (a handful of primitives) passing the serialized data around isn't a big deal, although you might want to  use something that's a bit lighter weight than JSON. If you have a large set of data (blobs, etc), then the performance hit from fetching the row off disk vs. serializing and deserializing is probably even or less. Ideally, you'd fetch the data only once and store it in a singleton, to be accessed by different activities, likely as POJOs.

Comment: static variables: very good advice which also solves my problems far beyond this question. Thanks very much... One question though: What is lighter than JSON? JSON is almost the lightest form of serialized data I can think of.

Comment: You're right, JSON is light as transmitted and renders quickly, but the parser is quite weighty. Bencode is lighter. The lightest I've used just concatenates <length>;<string> values, which boils down less than 10 lines of code + boilerplate.